# Error when sending emails through webform using EmailJS. 'The template ID is invalid'

Tags: reactjs

I've just recently added EmailJS to my website as a contact me form. I keep getting this error when I send myself a test email:
'bundle.js:1687          POST https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send-form 400'

The template ID is invalid. To find this ID, visit https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/templates

Does anyone know how I can fix this??

Answer (score 0):

There is a probability that you did not input one of the keys correctly.I realised i had added an extra letter to my service key and after ommiting it it worked perfectly